# Any reason for rip maximum metric is 15?

Tags: protocol-theory, rip

I am always getting confused with the statement "Rip protocol maximum diamter is 15" i.e maximum mteric for a route is 15 and metric with 16 is considered as inavlid .

Any reason for rip having maximum mteric is 15 ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't what I'd call a "hard reason" - ie something specific relating to hardware/software limitations. Ultimately it was a judgment call made by the designers of the protocol, who made this judgment call based on the convergence behavior of the protocol (slow), the "counting to infinity" problem, and ultimately they didn't believe RIP would be "practical" for networks with a diameter larger than 15.

> 1.1. Limitations of the protocol
>
> This protocol does not solve every possible routing problem.  As
>     mentioned above, it is primary intended for use as an IGP, in
>     reasonably homogeneous networks of moderate size.  In addition, the
>     following specific limitations should be mentioned:
>
> ```
>  - The protocol is limited to networks whose longest path
>    involves 15 hops.  The designers believe that the basic
>    protocol design is inappropriate for larger networks.  Note
>    that this statement of the limit assumes that a cost of 1
>    is used for each network.  This is the way RIP is normally
>    configured.  If the system administrator chooses to use
>    larger costs, the upper bound of 15 can easily become a
>    problem.
> ```
>
> ...
>    2. Distance Vector Algorithms
>
> ...
>
> As we mentioned above, the purpose of routing is to find a way to get
>     datagrams to their ultimate destinations.  Distance vector algorithms
>     are based on a table giving the best route to every destination in
>     the system.  Of course, in order to define which route is best, we
>     have to have some way of measuring goodness.  This is referred to as
>     the "metric".
>
> In simple networks, it is common to use a metric that simply counts
>     how many gateways a message must go through.  In more complex
>     networks, a metric is chosen to represent the total amount of delay
>     that the message suffers, the cost of sending it, or some other
>     quantity which may be minimized.  The main requirement is that it
>     must be possible to represent the metric as a sum of "costs" for
>     individual hops.

Keep in mind that at the time of its conception, the protocol was designed to operate on small, homogeneously (read: very slow serial links) connected networks.

All of this information is in the original RIP RFC, [RFC 1058](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc1058), which is readily available via a google search - it'd be great if you got the hint and started doing that instead of making this site the default go-to for these questions which have answers that are easily found with minimal research effort on your part.